# 12.04 Terminal Tab Color under gnome classic

Tags: gnome-terminal, ambiance

The tab color for gnome-terminal is different (light color) from the system Ambiance theme. What can I modify in

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
```

in order to get a consistent look for the tab color?

Comment: See this answer for tweaking the tab colours: http://askubuntu.com/questions/355297/gnome-terminal-tabs-no-contrast-between-active-and-inactive-tabs