# Gnome-terminal tabs: no contrast between active and inactive tabs

Tags: gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu 13.04, I often have multiple tabs open in gnome-terminal.  The problem is that, while I can set the title of each tab, it is very hard to tell which tab is active -- the color and rendering distinction between the active tab and the inactive tab is so subtle that one must study the tab bar very carefully.

Is there a way to make this contrast more obvious?

Comment: What is the name of the theme you are using?

Comment: Colorized distinction should be a sane default IMHO.  C'mon GNOME!

Comment: This problem is even more significant in `gedit`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with the Ambience theme - had the same problem.

Solution: edit `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (you might have to create it) and add:

```
TerminalWindow,
TerminalWindow.background {
        background-color: #6e6e6e;
        color: #000000;
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
        padding: 2;
        background-color: #6e6e6e;
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
        background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has the same issue. Your solution solved it for me.

Comment: Tried the tab:active block alone, no effect. :\ It appears that the file does not get noticed/read by a newly opened gnome-terminal. Could it be in the wrong place, does it have to be referenced from somewhere?

Comment: Forgot to add: I tried switching to another theme and back (as suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/a/221783/32201) and still no effect.

Comment: Perfect solution.  Has a few nuances with the way it blends with certain borders, but this is essentially exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 11):

Here is what worked for me in ubuntu 14.04,
I tried to maintain similar overall look, and make the inactive tabs less bright.

edit the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

to contain

```
TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
    background-color: #f5f4f3;
    foreground-color: #000000;
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
    background-color: #d2d1d0;
    foreground-color: #2e2d2c;
}
```

close **ALL** terminal windows
start and test

**EDIT**: After using that for a little while it became clear that a pronounced difference between active and inactive tab is not enough.

I think it is necessary to be able to tell an inactive tab at the first glance - without looking to its sides.

So here is the updated configuration (darker inactive tabs):

```
TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
    background-color: #f5f4f3;
    foreground-color: #000000;
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
    background-color: #a2a1a0;
    foreground-color: #1e1d1c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... this stretch of my life has passed by, but next time I get the problem I'll try that!

Comment: Awesome, Tjunkie, this works great on 15.04

Comment: It works in 15.10 too.

Comment: no gtk.css file there in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: foreground doesn't work on ubuntu 14.04 lts

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to make the text of the active tab more obvious you can modify it's label like this,

edit the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
TerminalTabLabel.active-page .label {
    color: cyan;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Tested in gnome-terminal 3.17.91

[image]

[image]

Here is what I'm using at work on Ubuntu 15.10 with gnome-terminal 3.16.2. The smaller tab size allows more screen area for the terminal to use and I've experimented with the contrast between active and inactive tabs. I think the tab label text looks better without the bold style applied.

```
/* gnome-terminal */
@define-color term-win-bg           #262626;
@define-color term-tab-inactive-bg  #333333;
@define-color term-tab-active-bg    #424242;
@define-color ubuntu-orange         #fb9267;

TerminalScreen {
    -TerminalScreen-background-darkness: 0.95;
    background-color: @term-win-bg;
}


TerminalWindow .notebook {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                from (alpha (shade (@term-win-bg, 0.9), 0.0)),
                                to (shade (@term-win-bg, 0.9))) 1;
    border-image-width: 0 1px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: shade(@term-tab-inactive-bg, 1);
}


TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: shade(@term-tab-active-bg, 1);
}


TerminalTabLabel.active-page .label {
    /*color: @bg_color;
    font-weight: bold
    color: @ubuntu-orange; */
    color: cyan;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Crazy color, but it works =)

Comment: I must admit my text colour choice is nicer with dark tabs :)

Comment: Feel free to remove my screenshot. ;)

Comment: Nah it's all good.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any problem to distinguish active and inactive tabs in gnome-terminal using the default Ubuntu theme - Ambiance.

Looking on Launchpad, I found that this is a confirmed bug affecting many people: [Difficult to distinguish which tab is selected](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/762349).

If this is affecting you also, you can solve this by changing your Ubuntu theme: right click on the desktop, select **Change Desktop Background** and in the new opened window change your theme to **High Contrast**:

[image: change ubuntu theme]

Then you can distinguish without problems your active and inactive tabs in gnome-terminal:

[image: terminal tabs]

Comment: Ok, that's an idea.  I guess I was hoping for something less global and dramatic than changing the entire desktop theme -- but if that's the only way, I guess it's worth it.   Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this for 14.04? Changing the whole theme feels like overkill. And High Contrast in particular is very ugly.

Comment: @becko The bug is being tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/762349 .  However, renedv1 's solution is very simple and effective: http://askubuntu.com/a/406816/31592