# Tilda: no contrast between active and inactive tabs

Tags: gnome-terminal, tabs, tilda

This topic is very close to what was suggested in [Gnome-terminal tabs: no contrast between active and inactive tabs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355297/gnome-terminal-tabs-no-contrast-between-active-and-inactive-tabs).
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and although the gtk.css configuration works fine with default gnome terminal, it does not apply to my tilda terminal.

Does anyone know how to get the same effect on tilda ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following configuration placed in `~/.config/tilda/style.css` file:

```
GtkWindow#Main {
    #background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-color: #000000;
}

GtkWindow#Main .notebook {
    padding: 0px;
}

GtkWindow#Main .notebook tab GtkLabel {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #505050;
}

GtkWindow#Main .notebook tab {
    background-color: #101010;
}

GtkWindow#Main .notebook tab:active {
    #background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    background-color: #181818;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm :) thanks !
Btw there was no style.css file in .config/tilda, how did you know that tilda would look for this file at start ?

Comment: Edit: I just found this github: https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda/wiki.
It may help others in the future.

Comment: Suggestions: add `border-radius: 4px;` in the **GtkLabel** properties to make the tabs look a bit more round. To change the border/highglight color, modify the **tab:active** `background-color` value with the color you want (I'm using `#28211C`, which is a light blue).