# Change Color of Gnome Terminal Open Tab bar in 16.04

Tags: command-line, themes, gnome-terminal

Aloha - I followed the instructions of the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355297/gnome-terminal-tabs-no-contrast-between-active-and-inactive-tabs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, it doesn't work for me on 16.04. Not sure if its that creating the gtk.css file method doesn't work on 16.04 or if I am just having an issue.

I use a non default theme, if that makes any difference. I have the base16 themes in a folder within .config and preloaded into terminal with 'source' command.

[image]

In the image you can see I have 2 open tabs, plus I show the output of my gtk.css file

Comment: The look of the tab bar (Gtk+ widget) has absolutely nothing to with the color palette used inside your terminal emulators (base16 in your case).